# Cannot use scanBleDevices to scan

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm tryig the library for the first time on kotlin, because of that I read that in order to scan first I need to implement it with 
`implementation "com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.10.0"`, create an RxBleClient and set the scan parameters, but it seems to be a problem with the method scanBleDevices().

I tried the code that appears on the description of the repository and the code from the kotlin example.

With the code from the description, there is only an error on scanBleDevices

```
rxBleClient = RxBleClient.create(this)

val scanSubscription = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
        new ScanSettings.Builder()
            // .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) // change if needed
            // .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) // change if needed
            .build()
        // add filters if needed
)
    .subscribe(
        {
            // Process scan result here.
        },
        {
            // Handle an error here.
        }
    );

// When done, just dispose.
scanSubscription.dispose();
```

With the code from the kotlin examples, there is also an error with the Observable that shows `No type arguments expected for class Observable`

```
private fun scanBleDevices(): Observable<ScanResult> {
        val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            .build()

        val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
             //.setDeviceAddress("B4:99:4C:34:DC:8B")
            // add custom filters if needed
            .build()

        return rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(scanSettings, scanFilter)
}
```

The problem occurs with the method scanBleDevices() that prompts an alert requesting scanSettings and scanFilter which they have been used it correctly:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
 scanBleDevices(ScanSettings!, vararg ScanFilter!) defined in com.polidea.rxandroidble2.RxBleClient
 scanBleDevices(vararg UUID!) defined in com.polidea.rxandroidble2.RxBleClient
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If compiler complains about `ScanSettings` and `ScanFilter` then check the package of those classes if you import them from `com.polidea.rxandroidble2` or from `android.bluetooth.le` (or similar)

The library accepts in this API only `ScanSettings` and `ScanFilter` classes from `com.polidea.rxandroidble2` package.

Comment: That was the problem, I didn't saw there was two different imports, thanks!